# Parsing of JSON string

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I want to parse json string in c# .NET
but it throws exception

```
string str= "{\"id\"=>\"\", \"textContent\"=>\"Services\", \"nodeName\"=>\"SPAN\", \"class\"=>\"ng-binding\", \"html\"=>\"<span class=\"ng-binding\">Services</span>\", \"rect\"=>{\"center_y\"=>252, \"center_x\"=>90, \"height\"=>26, \"width\"=>180, \"bottom\"=>108, \"left\"=>0, \"right\"=>90, \"y\"=>240, \"x\"=>0, \"top\"=>95}, \"nodeType\"=>\"ELEMENT_NODE\", \"webView\"=>\"NoResourceEntry-100\"}";
str = str.Replace("\"", "'");
str = str.Replace("=>", ":");
dynamic stuff = Json.Decode(str);

string name = stuff.id;
string address = stuff.textContent;
```

It will give exception

> A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in JsonProject.exe
>   The type initializer for 'System.Web.Helpers.Json' threw an exception.

Even if I am not replaceing " with ' still it will throw exception.

I have not used Json previously and very new to JSon. I have used calabash-android and there I get this jSON strings.

Comment: Your json is invalid. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: can you check if if the json gets "remodeled" correctly?, the final str that gets decoded? Run it through a json validator

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have a problem with just blindly replacing all `"` with `'` especially here `\"<span class=\"ng-binding\">Services</span>\"` as this would become `'<span class='ng-binding'>Services</span>'` which is not valid.

I would suggest using a Regex to replace `"` only where after an `=>` or before a `,`

Also as mentioned in the comments use the debugger to find out what `str` is after you're replace and use on online tool to check its valid

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not JSON.

Try this:

```
string str= @"
{""id"":"""", ""textContent"":""Services"", ""nodeName"":""SPAN"", ""class"":""ng-binding"", ""html"":""<span class='ng-binding'>Services</span>"", ""rect"":{""center_y"":252, ""center_x"":90, ""height"":26, ""width"":180, ""bottom"":108, ""left"":0, ""right"":90, ""y"":240, ""x"":0, ""top"":95}, ""nodeType"":""ELEMENT_NODE"", ""webView"":""NoResourceEntry-100""}
";

str = str.Replace("=>", ":");
str.Dump();
dynamic stuff = Json.Decode(str);

string name = stuff.id;
string address = stuff.textContent;
```

Comment: Its not working. On http://jsonlint.com/ If I replace => with : it will show valid json but in c# programe it throws exception

Answer (score 0):

Make change in your string as

```
<span class="ng-binding">Services</span>
```

to

```
<span class='ng-binding'>Services</span>
```

then replace your character.

```
str = str.Replace("\"", ""); //with blank value
str = str.Replace("=>", ":");
```

Finally your string is become like this.

```
{"id":"", "textContent":"Services", "nodeName":"SPAN", "class":"ng-binding", "html":"<span class='ng-binding'>Services</span>", "rect":{"center_y":252, "center_x":90, "height":26, "width":180, "bottom":108, "left":0, "right":90, "y":240, "x":0, "top":95}, "nodeType":"ELEMENT_NODE", "webView":"NoResourceEntry-100"}
```